# Laravel css not loading sometimes

Tags: html, css, laravel

This is a weird problem. On my login page the CSS will always load correctly.
But once i sign in to my application and get redirected to the dashboard, the CSS will almost always fail to load the first time although when i press F12 to see in the network tab if the CSS files are loaded; they are.. After some inactivity when i refresh the dashboard again the CSS may fail to load although the network tab sais it did load properly..

All CSS files exists and the HTML looks like this in the view:

```
    {{-- CSS --}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome/fontawesome.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome/solid.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome/regular.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/choices.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/common.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/dashboard.css') }}">
    @stack('css')
```

I have also tried to clean the browser cache with no luck.
Also i tried to `composer dump-autoload`, i don't know if that would help in any way but i tried it.. What could be causing this?

I have 2 images for reference.
The first one is when this weird error happens and the other one is how it looks just after i refresh it.

[image: Error]

[image: Successs]

Comment: When you make an HTTP request, the server normally returns code `200 OK`. If you set If-Modified-Since, the server may return `304 Not modified` (and the response will not have the content). This is supposed to be your cue that the page has not been modified.

Comment: Are you using mix to load the assets? try running ```npm run watch-poll``` .

Comment: @STA hmm.. Okay, thanks, i didn't understand much of that but i will take a look into the 304 code

Comment: @DanielaC.Montenegro I use mix to compile the sass files to the public directory.

Comment: Look up here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: @STA Ohh, i see! Trying out the versioning now, then ill need to wait a bit to check if it works or not, just post as answer and ill accept it if it works. Thanks!

Comment: versioning is just for production releases though, add this for prod 

if (mix.inProduction) {
    mix.version();
}

Change asset to mix in link tag

Comment: @STA Adding versioning didn't help at all. When taking a closer look, i saw i could scroll the page, and it looks like it's only the sidebar css thats not loaded correctly. The whole sidebar is a blade component im using in the dashboard layout, could that have anything to do with it?